# Is Sloan Dead or did he trick Bashir?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, section-31

In the DS9 episode ["Extreme Measures"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Extreme_Measures_(episode)), Bashir and O'Brien enter into Sloan's mind to find a cure for Odo. Sloan, who is unwilling to give up the cure, attempts suicide by releasing a toxin into his body, so he will slowly die.

**Questions**:

1. We've seen before that [Sloan was able to fake his death by
   vaporizing](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Inter_Arma_Enim_Silent_Leges_(episode)), so did he find a way to suppress his vital signs
   from star fleet medical equipment, and hide a pulse so that to the
   doctor he was "dead"?
2. Is there any indication that Bashir and O'Brien actually escaped Sloan's mind? Two episodes later was the series finale, did it all occur in a dream?

Earlier in the episode Bashir and O'Brien believed they escaped, but Bashir picked up a book and realized they were still in a dream because the book was incomplete; Sloan was reconstructing it from Bashir's memory.

However, Sloan could have reconstructed his dream to make Bashir think he's misplaced the book, and eventually Bashir would have forgotten about it.

Comment: You can question anything in Star Trek. Maybe Sloan is really a member of the Q. It's best to go by what the show plainly says.

Comment: @HamSandwich - The show doesn't really say much about Sloan, he faked his death, and can you really trust anything he says?

Comment: He's not trustworthy, but at the end, it's stated that he died. That's canon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All indications are that they escaped successfully and that Sloan actually died

> [Bashir stands up, clears the cobwebs, then looks over to a shaky O'Brien, sitting up from his bio-bed. **Bashir then gazes at Sloan's body, lying motionless on the bio-bed.]**
>
> **BASHIR:** *Sloan?*
>
> **SISKO:** ***He died** about two minutes ago... Almost took you with him.*
>
> [Bashir glances back at O'Brien.]
>
> <sub><sup>[Extreme Measures - Original Screenplay](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/573.txt)</sup></sub>

It seems extremely likely that Bashir would have conducted a full autopsy on the body (which would largely rule out any transporter *bait & switch* jiggery pokery) and given that that Sloan was incapable of creating a realistic artificial environment for Bashir and O'Brien means that it would be trivially simple for them to check whether they were still inside his mind by simply picking up an unread book or medical journal and turning to page one.

---

The actor who portrayed Sloan, William Sadler was also given to understand that he did indeed die.

> **You appeared in three episodes, but were there plans to see more of Sloan? Did (writer-producer) Ira Steven Behr ever tell you?**
>
> **Sadler:** *I think it was always planned that Sloan would die in the third one. I think they planned it as an in and out thing for this
> character, though there was a lot of space between the episodes. And
> my last one was a couple of episodes before the series ended. But no
> one ever said anything, that they were thinking of me for three or
> less or more.*
>
> <sub><sup>[*StarTrek.com - Luther Sloan from Deep Space Nine - William Sadler*](https://intl.startrek.com/article/luther-sloan-from-deep-space-nine-william-sadler)</sup></sub>

---

Sloan's official record on StarTrek.com indicates that he's dead.

> **Sloan**
>
> Amoral agent in a secretive division of Starfleet Intelligence called Section 31 who repeatedly tried to recruit Dr. Julian Bashir into the covert agency. **In 2375 Sloan committed suicide** rather than give up the cure for the Founders Disease, but Bashir and Miles O'Brien recovered the information anyway.
>
> <sub><sup>[StarTrek.com Database - Sloan](https://intl.startrek.com/database_article/sloan)</sup></sub>

---

The timeline in the EU novel [Star Trek: Avatar](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine_-_Avatar) indicates that he's dead.

> **2375**
>
> Bashir extracts the cure to the Founder disease from the mind of Section 31 operative Luther Sloan. S**loan commits suicide**, but Bashir succeeds in curing Odo.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Trek: Deep Space Nine - Avatar](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine_-_Avatar)</sup></sub>

---

Sloan's article in the (canon) [Star Trek Encyclopedia](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Encyclopedia) is also similarly blunt.

> [image]
> <sub><sup>"*Sloan committed suicide in late 2375...*"</sup></sub>
>
> <sub><sup>Star Trek Encyclopedia - 3rd Edition - Supplement p683</sup></sub>

Comment: He’s dead, Jim.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Unless he's not.

Comment: Sloan might still be around even if *that* Sloan died. Section 31 must have their own version of Vorta cloning and memory-transfer technology.

Comment: @Gaultheria - Bashir and Crusher were both adept at spotting that the corpses in front of them weren't real people/clones and I think it's likely that Bashir would have performed *every possible check* to ensure that it genuinely was Sloan and not some kind of duplicate.

Comment: I'm assuming Section 31 uses sufficiently advanced technology to avoid detection, and that they choose not to publish their research. They didn't particularly care about their comm badges becoming known in *Discovery*, and that tech was many decades ahead of Starfleet's. Imagine how far ahead they could be with tech they're *trying* to keep secret.

Comment: @Gaultheria - The fact that they were operating openly in Star Trek: STD is one of the most glaring breaks with canon